# Event of underlying canvas interrupts slider

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a canvas and a user control defined as follows:

```
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="0">

            <Canvas Name="GameCanvas">

                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform x:Name="CanvasRenderTransform" />
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>

                <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    <toolkit:GestureListener DragStarted="GestureListener_DragStarted" DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta" Tap="GestureListener_Tap" PinchStarted="GestureListener_PinchStarted" PinchDelta="GestureListener_PinchDelta"/>
                </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>

            </Canvas>

            <Client:TileMenu HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="TileOverlayMenu" />

        </Grid>
```

The `<Client:TileMenu>` is a user control that contains some textboxes, a slider and two buttons.

The problem here is that when I use the slider it is interrupted, forcing me to slide over and over to get to the wanted value.

If I remove the `<toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>` the slider in the user control works as intended.

The user control sits upon the `<Canvas>`, so is there a way I can disable the events? On all the events in the Canvas's events I have `if (TileOverlayMenu.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible) return;` but it still bugged.

Comment: What code is in the eventhandlers you have on the toolkit:GestureListener ?

Comment: I'm doing a lot, but because of the if test it should not be relevant